# Zabbix JMX Tomcat8 monitoring fails

Tags: java-8, jmx, tomcat8, zabbix

I'm trying to monitor Tomcat8 with JDK8 using JMX.
I have setup my agents and modified the startup.sh.

On my zabbix_java_gateway.log I get the following exception:

> WARN  com.zabbix.gateway.SocketProcessor - error processing request
>   com.zabbix.gateway.ZabbixException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   connection timed out:
>   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://server1.example.com:10052/jmxrmi
>           at com.zabbix.gateway.JMXItemChecker.getValues(JMXItemChecker.java:97)
>   ~[zabbix-java-gateway-2.4.7.jar:na]
>           at com.zabbix.gateway.SocketProcessor.run(SocketProcessor.java:63)
>   ~[zabbix-java-gateway-2.4.7.jar:na]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_71]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_71]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connection timed out:
>   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://server1.example.com:10052/jmxrmi
>           at com.zabbix.gateway.ZabbixJMXConnectorFactory.connect(ZabbixJMXConnectorFactory.java:123)
>   ~[zabbix-java-gateway-2.4.7.jar:na]
>           at com.zabbix.gateway.JMXItemChecker.getValues(JMXItemChecker.java:89)
>   ~[zabbix-java-gateway-2.4.7.jar:na]
>           ... 4 common frames omitted

On my *startup.sh* I added the following to the CATALINA_OPTS

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10052 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/opt/tomcat-latest/conf/jmxremote.password
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/tomcat-latest/conf/jmxremote.access
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server1.example.com

My *zabbix_agentd.conf* contains the following:

> PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid LogFile=/var/log/zabbix_agentd.log
>   LogFileSize=1 DebugLevel=3 Server=monitor.example.com
>   Hostname=server1.example.com ListenPort=10050 StartAgents=5 Timeout=30

I have already done the following:

1. successfully connected to the server using jconsole
2. remove authentication
3. telnet the server over port 10050 / 10052

The weird part is that the same setup works well for Tomcat6 with JDK7.

### EDIT 1

I've updated the JDK version on the zabbix server to be newer than the JDK installed on my JAVA nodes - still same result - it ends with

> ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [4] Interrupted system call

### UPDATE

So I figured it out eventually.
I had on my tomcat configuration file `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server1.example.com`
I miss understood that the hostname should be set to the monitoring server and to the monitored server hostname.
Apparently, there's a bug on Tomcat 6 and this directive does not work.
Remove it solved the problem completely.

Thanks,

Liron

Comment: Could you please check whether zabbix_agentd.conf configuration is relevant here? JMX monitoring in Zabbix does not involve Zabbix agent - only Zabbix server and Zabbix Java gateway.

Comment: You are correct - the zabbix conf file is not relevant.